What is the correct way to use \Form or \begin{Form}...\end{Form}?
I have a project requiring many form entry fields. According to the hyperref docs (p. 43) the document must include either \begin{Form}...\end{Form} surrounding the form field(s) or \Form at the beginning of the document, and either must be used only once in the document.
In my experimentation, I have compiled the MWE using only \Form, only the \begin{Form}...\end{Form} paired by baz, and finally only the two inner environments paired with foo and bar respectively. The output was the same in every case and the console and log shows no errors or warnings.
My ultimate question what is the correct way to use multiple form fields in a single document?
My MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[language=english]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\Form
%\begin{Form} %----- baz
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\bigskip
%\begin{Form} %----- foo
\TextField[%
  name=questionone,%
  width=0.9\linewidth,%
  height=2in,%
  charsize=10pt,%
  value={Type your resonse here.},%
  bordercolor=black,%
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,%
  multiline=true,]{}
%\end{Form}   %----- foo
\bigskip

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\bigskip
%\begin{Form} %----- bar
\TextField[%
  name=questiontwo,%
  width=0.9\linewidth,%
  height=2in,%
  charsize=10pt,%
  value={Type your resonse here.},%
  bordercolor=black,%
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,%
  multiline=true,]{}
%\end{Form}   %----- bar
\bigskip

\lipsum[1][1-4]

%\end{Form}   %----- baz
\end{document}


I would simply use \Form. The begin/end version only adds an unneeded group.

I've always used \begin{form} ... \end{form} but I probably shouldn't if @UlrikeFischer says not. there's no problem with multiple fields. you just add multiple fields.

Okay \Form it is.
